# Elegant solution required - look forward, check condition, fill gap if condition met

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am looking for a faster solution (ideally vectorised) for the problem below.

I want to fill gaps, <= 5 rows long (between 1's e.g. index 0,1,2 should not be filled as there is no 1 beforehand) where they are followed by another value above threshold within that window. Currently, when this is scaled up with the large df (currently commented out), it takes 10 secs to complete. I have played around with shifting the columns to come up with a vectorised approach, but I have had no luck so have currently settled for a procedural one.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data'], data=[0,0,0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,0,0,0,0,0,7.2,7.2,0,7.2,0,7.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.2,0,7.2])
# df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data'], data=[0,0,0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,0,0,0,0,0,7.2,7.2,0,7.2,0,7.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.2,0,7.2]*2000)


df['above_threshold'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 7 else 0)
df['above_threshold_filled'] = df['above_threshold']

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx < len(df) - 6:
        if (row['above_threshold_filled'] == 1) & (df.loc[idx+1, 'above_threshold_filled'] == 0):  
            if (df.loc[idx+1:idx+6, 'above_threshold_filled'].sum() > 0):
                for i in range(idx+1,idx+6):
                    if df.loc[i, 'above_threshold_filled'] == 0: 
                        df.loc[i, 'above_threshold_filled'] = 1
                    else:
                        break
end = time.time()
print("Time:",end - start)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
thresh = 7
N = 5

df['above_threshold'] = df['data'].gt(thresh).astype(int)

# group by 0s followed by a 1
group  = df.loc[::-1, 'above_threshold'].cumsum()

# fill only if the group has ≤ N+1 items
df['above_threshold_filled'] = (df.groupby(group)
                                   ['above_threshold']
                                  .transform(lambda x: 1 if len(x)<=6 else x)
                                  .where(group>0, 0)
                               )
```

Alternative that might be faster:

```
thresh = 7
N = 5

m1 = df['data'].gt(thresh)
df['above_threshold'] = m1.astype(int)

group  = df.loc[::-1, 'above_threshold'].cumsum()
m2 = df.groupby(group)['above_threshold'].transform('size').le(N+1)

df['above_threshold_filled'] = (m1|m2).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    data  above_threshold  above_threshold_filled
0    0.0                0                       1
1    0.0                0                       1
2    0.0                0                       1
3    7.1                1                       1
4    7.2                1                       1
5    7.3                1                       1
6    7.4                1                       1
7    0.0                0                       1
8    0.0                0                       1
9    0.0                0                       1
10   0.0                0                       1
11   0.0                0                       1
12   7.2                1                       1
13   7.2                1                       1
14   0.0                0                       1
15   7.2                1                       1
16   0.0                0                       1
17   7.2                1                       1
18   0.0                0                       0
19   0.0                0                       0
20   0.0                0                       0
21   0.0                0                       0
22   0.0                0                       0
23   0.0                0                       0
24   0.0                0                       0
25   0.0                0                       0
26   7.2                1                       1
27   0.0                0                       1
28   7.2                1                       1
```

##### only filling inner 0s

```
thresh = 7
N = 5

m0 = df['data'].gt(thresh)
df['above_threshold'] = m0.astype(int)

group1  = df['above_threshold'].cumsum()
group2  = df.loc[::-1, 'above_threshold'].cumsum()
m1 = df[group1>0].groupby(group1)['above_threshold'].transform('size').le(N+1)
m2 = df[group2>0].groupby(group2)['above_threshold'].transform('size').le(N+1)

df['above_threshold_filled'] = (m0|(m1&m2)).astype(int)
```

Or with help of [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
thresh = 7
N = 5

df['above_threshold'] = df['data'].gt(thresh).astype(int)

s = df['above_threshold'].where(df['above_threshold'].eq(1)).interpolate(limit_area='inside').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
m = df.groupby(df['above_threshold'].cumsum())['above_threshold'].transform('size').le(N+1)
df['above_threshold_filled'] = s.where(m, 0)
```

Output:

```
    data  above_threshold  above_threshold_filled
0    0.0                0                       0
1    0.0                0                       0
2    0.0                0                       0
3    7.1                1                       1
4    7.2                1                       1
5    7.3                1                       1
6    7.4                1                       1
7    0.0                0                       1
8    0.0                0                       1
9    0.0                0                       1
10   0.0                0                       1
11   0.0                0                       1
12   7.2                1                       1
13   7.2                1                       1
14   0.0                0                       1
15   7.2                1                       1
16   0.0                0                       1
17   7.2                1                       0
18   0.0                0                       0
19   0.0                0                       0
20   0.0                0                       0
21   0.0                0                       0
22   0.0                0                       0
23   0.0                0                       0
24   0.0                0                       0
25   0.0                0                       0
26   7.2                1                       1
27   0.0                0                       1
28   7.2                1                       1
```

Comment: These are indeed very quick, especially the second option, thanks. However, the methods fill the first three values (index=[0,1,2]) which they shouldn't.

Comment: Why not? Your condition was to fill the 0s that are ≤ 5 successive and followed by a 1, those 3 rows are followed by a 1.

Comment: If the logic is different, you might want to break it down in your example

Comment: I see your point. We are filling a gap though, so without any prior information e.g. a 1, we have nothing to judge the decision on as to whether the gap should be filled.  I should of stated I wanted to fill gaps between 1's, I will update.

Comment: I've just sliced the data frame to the first non-zero value in 'above_threshold' which will suit my task. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim any logic can be valid depending on the context, which is why I had answered according to the description. I added a second part to my answer for filling only internal 0s